# Ladder times of a Brownian motion with drift

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

Let $(B_s)_{s_\geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and fix $t>0$. For $u>0$, set $T_u=\inf\{s>0, B_s+s t>u\}$. Now consider $x>0$ such that $\sup_{0 \leq s \leq x} (B_s+st)=B_x+xt$ and such that $T=(T_u) $ jumps at $u=B_x+xt$. Is it the case that $B$ achieves a local maximum at $x$?

Comment: This seems to be closely related to the question "If $(B_s)$ has a local maximum time $x$, then does $B_s+st$ also have a local maximum at time $x$?". A positive answer to this question would imply a positive answer to your question. I suspect the answer to this question is yes...

Comment: What is $T$ and what do you mean by "$T$ jumps at $x$"?

Comment: Anthony Quas: I would say that around a local maximum Brownian motion looks likes two upside-down Brownian excursions glued together, and since $\epsilon(s)/s \rightarrow \infty$ as $s\rightarrow 0$ for a Brownian excursion $\epsilon$, this would imply that if $x$ is a local maximum of $(B_s)$, then $x$ is a local maximum of $(B_s+st)$ for $t$ large enough. The question is if the converse is true.

Iosif Pinelis : $T$ is the process defined in the question; by "$T$ jumps at $x$" I mean that the subordinator $u \mapsto T_u$ jumps at time $x$.

Comment: @Gagar : I guess you meant to say that $T=(T_u)$ and $u\mapsto T_u$ jumps at $u=B_x+xt$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for the typo! I'll edit the question.